# Can I add domain for Microsoft 365 Basic subscription?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, domain

Ì'm thinking of moving my domain from Google to outlook.com and I'm confused if it will be allowed to add domain to my subscription or if it just is for outlook.com users.

> **Add an existing domain to your Microsoft 365 Business Basic subscription**
>
> When you purchase Microsoft 365 Business Basic, you have the option of
> using a domain you own, or buying one during the sign-up.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/setup-business-basic?view=o365-worldwide#add-an-existing-domain-to-your-microsoft-365-business-basic-subscription

On some pages I find it says "Business Basic", and at some other pages it says just "Business".

Do anyone know if custom domains are supported with the "Basic"-subscription that only has Outlook and Onedrive?

Comment: Try posting on Webmasters site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add domain for Microsoft 365 Basic subscription?

Yes. To add subdomains, you must manage your own DNS settings at your registrar’s website. If you are letting Microsoft manage your DNS settings with NS records, or if you bought the domain from Microsoft, you can’t add subdomains. Typically, you could add up to 5,000 domains to your Microsoft 365 subscription.